# How CipherInputStream input buffer size can affects app's security?

Tags: java, android, security, inputstream, javax.crypto

My android application is loading image from CipherInputStream. It takes too long for BitmapFactory to encode it. So with the use of reflection I've changed CipherInputStream inputBuffer size from 20 to 32768. After that loading starts working in 5-10 times faster. The question is how this manipulations with CipherInputStream  could  affect application's security?

Answer (score 0):

It should not affect it at all. Your security is derived from the fact that no-one knows your secret key. The size of the data you happen to decrypt with that key is not relevant.